# Why cant I use an XPath expression with the node names

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am having an issue understanding why I cannot use an XPath expression using the node name after I have converted a Tree Fragment into a node-set using the msxsl:node-set() function but can use the node array index.

Here is my XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"  extension-element-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="ConsumerInfoTag">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="BureauResponse/ConsumerInfoNO04">
            <xsl:copy-of select="BureauResponse/ConsumerInfoNO04" />
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="BureauResponse/ConsumerInfoNO05">
            <xsl:copy-of select="BureauResponse/ConsumerInfoNO05" />
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy-of select="Unknown" />
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:variable name="IDNumber" select="msxsl:node-set($ConsumerInfoTag)/node()[1]/node()[6]" />
      <xsl:variable name="PassportNumber" select="msxsl:node-set($ConsumerInfoTag)/IdentityNo2" />
      <xsl:variable name="FullName">
        <xsl:value-of select="msxsl:node-set($ConsumerInfoTag)/Forename1" />
        <xsl:value-of select="''" />
        <xsl:value-of select="msxsl:node-set($ConsumerInfoTag)/Surname" />
      </xsl:variable>
      <html>
        <body>
          <table width="800px">
            <tr>
              <td>
                Name
              </td>
              <td>
                ID
              </td>
              <td>
                Passport
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="$FullName" />
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="$IDNumber" />
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="$PassportNumber" />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </body>
      </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And here is my test XML:

```
<BureauResponse xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <ConsumerInfoNO04>
            <Surname>Bloggs</Surname>
            <Forename1>Joe</Forename1>
            <IdentityNo1>1234567890</IdentityNo1>
            <IdentityNo2>0987654321</IdentityNo2>
        </ConsumerInfoNO04>
    </BureauResponse>
```

As you see in the XSL `msxsl:node-set($ConsumerInfoTag)/node()[1]/node()[6]` will assign the correct value but `msxsl:node-set($ConsumerInfoTag)/IdentityNo1` will not as shown for the passport and fullname. Also I am pretty sure it was working before, but now I am starting to doubt myself.

I am using c# XslCompiledTransform() to call the stylesheet, Please could someone point out my silly mistake or in the direction of what is preventing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need `*/IdentityNo1` as you can have different parent elements for that identity no element.

Comment: Ah I see it was a silly mistake but thanks for helping me see it so quickly, I have changed `<xsl:copy-of select="BureauResponse/ConsumerInfoNO04" />` to `<xsl:copy-of select="BureauResponse/ConsumerInfoNO04/*" />` this gives me a tree fragment of all the child nodes of ConsumerInfo rather than a tree fragment of ConsumerInfo and its children.

Answer (score 0):

So a bit of a rookie error but I will leave this here for future understanding.

xsl:copy-of gives an inclusive Tree Fragment of the node you select so therefore when using node-set() the node you select becomes the first node.

As @martinhonnen mentioned I needed to adjust the XPath expression to be:
`<xsl:variable name="IDNumber" select="msxsl:node-set($ConsumerInfoTag)/*/IdentityNo1" />`
to get the the nodes I wanted.

How I ended up solving it was by selecting all child nodes of the ConsumerInfo node like:
`<xsl:copy-of select="BureauResponse/ConsumerInfoNO04/*" />` to simplify my expression.

Thanks again Martin.